# Some hint about DB Modeling

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization

i was studying about normalization forms and then came a doubt:

Let's say i have a table Company (pk, CompanyName). 
Company may have one or more telephone numbers (1:N).
Company may have one or more representatives (pk, RepresentativeName) (1:N).
Each os this representatives may have one or more telephone numbers (1:N).

Don't know why but feels wrong create a separate table for Company's Telephones and for Representative's Telephone. The fields are the same (pk, areacode, number), so it should be stored in the same table.

Then, lets make a single Telephone table. But when comes to FK, it may not work properly.

1 CompanyA

2 CompanyB

3 CompanyC

1 RepresentativeA

2 RepresentativeB

3 RepresentativeC

If my Telephone table is (PK, FK, AreaCode, Number) Company PK and Representative PK will have the same value and the search will return wrong values.

If my Telephone table is (PK, CFK, RFK AreaCode, Number) there will be blank cells and again, just feels wrong.

So, anyone has an, let me see, "Elegant Solution"?

Answer (score 0):

Lets look into the situation:
1. You need one telephone table
2. The tables contains record for Representative telephone and Company telephone
3. The FK that points to Representative table ot to Compnay table are non distinguishable(i.e say same kind of numeric values) 
4. You don't want to have two different FK column in Telephone table

Now while running the query there should be some way to differentiate the telephones whether it belong to a campany or to a representative. You can do it by adding a column calles Telephone type in Telephone table. That column can hold value like C or R to represent whether the telephone is for Company or for a Representative.